# What's an 'embassy trip'?

Tags: meaning

I ran into this sentence:

> *"I met him during my **embassy trip** to England"*.

I googled **'embassy trip'** and a lot of people are saying that an **'embassy trip'** is their way to go to the embassy. And I also found people who are trying to book a place nearby embassy.

But I don't think that's the meaning of **'embassy trip'** in this sentence. I have no other context. I found a lot of *'**embassy trip** to somewhere'*, but couldn't find its meaning.

Comment: Perhaps the speaker was connected in some way with their country's ambassador to Britain, and travelled to London with him/her?

Comment: Did you find the sentence here? https://indexsubtitle.com/translate/journey-to-china-the-mystery-of-iron-mask/2334293/Journey.to.China.The.Mystery.of.Iron.Mask.2019.1080p.US.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG.srt Seems to be taken from a movie called "The Mystery of Iron Mask"

Comment: The answer can be easily discovered by looking up the meaning of ["embassy"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/embassy) The speaker made a trip to England to see someone at an embassy, when the speaker met "him". Was this person at the embassy or was it a casual meeting at a friend's house or in a pub, we don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have several meanings. I'll focus on official trips to meet influential people. For example

> The Embassy trip to Edinburgh & Glasgow 13 April 2020
>
> **To have meeting with members of Parliament, Government, Universites,
> businesses** (TBC) VIETNAM – UK NETWORK is an umbrella group bringing
> together organisations and individuals with shared interests in
> Vietnam to promote Vietnam – UK
> https://www.vietnamuknetwork.org.uk/news/the-embassy-trip-to-edinburgh-glasgow/

I don't know who is allowed to go on these trips but my guess is business leaders and politicians. To find out more, one would have to contact the organisation.

---

**Note**

There is always context. It is any information that will help us answer your question. For example "a piece of paper floated down from the sky with this phrase written on it", or "I found this example in *The Dictionary of Useful Phrases*". If you found the phrase online then a link to the text is always useful.